# How to share a global.d.ts from several packages in monorepo

Tags: typescript, monorepo

I have my interface definitions of the result of several database queries in a `global.d.ts` file.  As I moved the various project folders using those interfaces into a single monorepo, I am still using a copy of the same `global.d.ts` in each package as it was before, and it works fine, except for the duplication, which makes little sense in the monorepo.

I have a shared `tsconfig.json` file at the root, which is extended by the `tsconfig.json` in each package.

How can I move the `global.d.ts` file to the root of the monorepo and have all the packages use it without importing it into each source file?

I tried changing in the tsconfig of each package:

```
"include": ["./src/**/*"],
// into
"include": ["./src/**/*", "../../types/**/*"],
```

I tried adding the `typeRoots` in the root tsconfig:

```
"typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", ".types"]
```

All to no avail.

Summary:  I just want to move the two identical copies of the currently working `global.d.ts` files in each package, to a single file in a common location and make tsc find it just as it does when there is one copy in each package.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @timarcosdias Thanks for reminding me of my own question.  I found a solution, not the one I was looking for but I'm happy with it.  See below.

Answer (score 12):

Answer to self (sorry, I logged in with a different account, I should fix that, I don't know how I got different accounts).

The best solution I found is using `reference`:

```
/// <reference path="../../types/global.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../types/api.d.ts" />
```

In this example, the `types` folder is at the root of the mono-repo, it is not a package but it might have been one, it doesn't really matter, your choice. I have split the single `global.d.ts` which I originally meant to have, into several more specific ones.   The reference needs to be in any file just once in each package. I opted to put it in the root `index.ts` or `index.tsx` file which seems the most appropriate place for it.

I like this solution better than the one I was originally looking for because, it is not bothersome, as the reference must be made just once, not in every single file, and it allows me to split the definitions into various declaration files used on-demand, instead of a single one with everything piled up together.